# django virtualenv - Error: No module named south

Tags: python, django, virtualenv, django-south

I'm getting this error, when I try this:

> source ./env/bin/activate
>
> sudo python manage.py syncdb
>
> Error: No module named south

I installed south after activating virtual env, using pip install south (as well as django).

installed apps in settings.py:

```
INSTALLED_APPS = (
    'south',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.sites',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
```

What could be the problem?

Update:
I get this error when trying to sync without sudo. Maybe it is related with 'south' problem:

(env)andrius@ubuntu:~/djcode/myproject$ python manage.py syncdb

```
Syncing...
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 10, in <module>
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "/home/andrius/env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 443, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "/home/andrius/env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 382, in execute
    self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
  File "/home/andrius/env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 196, in run_from_argv
    self.execute(*args, **options.__dict__)
  File "/home/andrius/env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 232, in execute
    output = self.handle(*args, **options)
  File "/home/andrius/env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 371, in handle
    return self.handle_noargs(**options)
  File "/home/andrius/env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/south/management/commands/syncdb.py", line 90, in handle_noargs
    syncdb.Command().execute(**options)
  File "/home/andrius/env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 232, in execute
    output = self.handle(*args, **options)
  File "/home/andrius/env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 371, in handle
    return self.handle_noargs(**options)
  File "/home/andrius/env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/commands/syncdb.py", line 57, in handle_noargs
    cursor = connection.cursor()
  File "/home/andrius/env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/backends/__init__.py", line 306, in cursor
    cursor = self.make_debug_cursor(self._cursor())
  File "/home/andrius/env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/backends/postgresql_psycopg2/base.py", line 177, in _cursor
    self.connection = Database.connect(**conn_params)
  File "/home/andrius/env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/psycopg2-2.4.6-py2.7-linux-x86_64.egg/psycopg2/__init__.py", line 178, in connect
    return _connect(dsn, connection_factory=connection_factory, async=async)
psycopg2.OperationalError: FATAL:  Peer authentication failed for user "django"
```

I created database and user for database using these commands:

```
template1=# create database finance;
CREATE DATABASE
template1=# grant all privileges on database finance to django;
ERROR:  role "django" does not exist
template1=# create user django with password 'mydb123';
CREATE ROLE
template1=# grant all privileges on database finance to django;
GRANT
template1=# \q
```

My database settings in settings.py:

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.postgresql_psycopg2', # Add 'postgresql_psycopg2', 'mysql', 'sqlite3' or 'oracle'.
        'NAME': 'finance',                      # Or path to database file if using sqlite3.
        'USER': 'django',                      # Not used with sqlite3.
        'PASSWORD': 'mydb123',                  # Not used with sqlite3.
        'HOST': '',                      # Set to empty string for localhost. Not used with sqlite3.
        'PORT': '',                      # Set to empty string for default. Not used with sqlite3.
    }
```

}

Comment: Try to put south at the end of your installed apps:
_Now you’ve installed South system-wide, you’ll need to configure Django to use it. Doing so is simple; just edit your settings.py and add 'south' to the end of INSTALLED_APPS._ (http://south.readthedocs.org/en/0.7.6/installation.html#configuring-your-django-installation)

Comment: Activate your virtualenv, start python and try "import south" from the interactive shell. Did it work?

Comment: Actually I put it at the end of installed apps first. It gives the same error though. I think it should be ok with south path, because django is in the same directory as south and django apps don't give this error.

Comment: @DanielEriksson Yes in interactive shell it worked.

Comment: So don't get it why it gives this error when in interactive shell it seems to see south module...

Comment: Not sure if it is related, but why are you using sudo?

Comment: When I didn't use sudo, I got error that peer was not authenticated (so I thought it didn't have permission to do this command, so I used sudo and got this error). I will post what error it is giving me when I'm using it without sudo.

Comment: You can try to append the site-packages directory of the virtualenv to your PYTHON_PATH, inside the manage.py file.

Comment: @JordanJambazov You mean with os.path?

Comment: set `'HOST': '127.0.0.1',` and try to syncdb without sudo

Comment: @sneawo Oh thanks!. when I put it to 'Host', it worked!. I wonder why it didn't work with default (as it should be localhost).

Comment: @orp, something like this: `import sys, os; sys.path.append(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)) + '/../ENV/lib/python2.7/site-packages')`

Comment: @JordanJambazov tried append, but got same error, but sneawo solution helped.

Answer (score 8):

dont  be a  sudoer  when installing south or running syncdb. just do

```
pip install south
python manage.py syncdb
```

Comment: Usually I don't use sudo, but I thought it required sudo, because of authentication error. My bad:)

Answer (score 0):

Just Remove south from installed apps

Django 1.7 and higher do not need South

To remove south  use pip uninstall south then y to completely remove it

Comment: For me, `south` is not in installed apps but I still get this error. And `pip uninstall south` reports: `south is not installed`